# R + Highcharter + Shinydashboard: How to create reactive mouse event?

Tags: r, shiny, mouseevent, shinydashboard, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a board where on one side the map of the United States would be represented and on the other, what I would like to do is that when the client passes the mouse cursor over one of the states, a graph is created where the data can be viewed.

[DataSource](https://www.kaggle.com/hemil26/mass-shootings-in-united-states-20182022)

**The code I am using is the following:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)


massShooting2018 <- read.csv('shootings_2018.csv')
massShooting2019 <- read.csv('shootings_2019.csv')
massShooting2020 <- read.csv('shootings_2020.csv')
massShooting2021 <- read.csv('shootings_2021.csv')
massShooting2022 <- read.csv('shootings_2022.csv')

massShootings <- rbind(massShooting2018,
                       massShooting2019,
                       massShooting2020,
                       massShooting2021,
                       massShooting2022)

massShootings.clean <- massShootings %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date))

massShootings.order <- massShootings.clean %>%
  group_by(date, state) %>%
  summarise(dead = sum(dead),
            injured = sum(injured),
            total = sum(total),
            description, .groups = 'drop')

years <- massShootings.order %>%
  sample_frac(1) %>%
  select(date) %>%
  mutate(date = year(date)) %>%
  arrange(date)

hc_my_theme <- hc_theme_merge(hc_theme_flatdark(),
                              hc_theme(chart = list(backgroundColor = '#242f39'),
                                       subtitle = list(style = list(color = '#a7a5a5'))))


header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Map Test')

sideBar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(fluidPage(column(width = 4,
                                       offset = 4,
                                       selectInput('year',
                                                   label = 'Year',
                                                   choices = unique(years),
                                                   selected = 2018,
                                                   width = "100%"))),
                      box(title = "Map",
                          status = "primary",
                          solidHeader = TRUE,
                          collapsible = TRUE,
                          highchartOutput('mapPlot')),                      
                      box(title = 'line',
                          solidHeader = TRUE,
                          collapsible = TRUE,
                          highchartOutput('linePlot')))

ui <- dashboardPage(header,
                    sideBar,
                    body)


server <- function(input,
                   output,
                   session)
{
  df <- reactive({df <- massShootings.order %>%
    filter(year(date) >= input$year[1] & year(date) <= input$year) %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    summarise(dead = sum(dead),
              injured = sum(injured),
              total = sum(total),
              description, .groups = 'drop')})
  
  
  output$mapPlot <- renderHighchart({
  hcmap(map = 'countries/us/custom/us-all-mainland.js',
        data = df(),
        joinBy = c('name', 'state'),
        value = 'total',
        borderWidth = 0.05,
        nullColor = "#d3d3d3") %>%
    hc_title(text = 'Mass Shooting') %>%
    hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops(colors = viridisLite::viridis(10,
                                                                   begin = 0.1)),
                 type = "logarithmic") %>%
    hc_tooltip(formatter= JS("function () { return this.point.name.bold() +
                            ' <br />' +
                            ' <br /> <b>Dead:</b> ' + this.point.dead +
                            ' <br /> <b>Injured:</b> ' + this.point.injured ;}")) %>%
    hc_add_theme(hc_my_theme) %>%
    hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE) %>%
    hc_credits(enabled = FALSE) %>%
    hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)})
  
  
  output$linePlot <- renderHighchart({highchart(type = "stock") %>%
      hc_chart("line",
               name = "base",
               hcaes(x = date)) %>%
      hc_add_series(massShootings.order,
                    name = "Total",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = total)) %>%
      hc_add_series(massShootings.order,
                    name = "Dead",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = dead)) %>%
      hc_add_series(massShootings.order,
                    name = "Injured",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = injured)) %>%
      hc_tooltip(
        crosshairs = TRUE,
        shared = TRUE,
        borderWidth = 2,
        table = TRUE)})
  
  
  datag <- reactive({

    highchartProxy("mapPlot") %>%
      hcpxy_loading(action = "show")})

  observeEvent(input$mapPlot_mouseOver, {
    datag <- datag()

    print(input$mapPlot_mouuseOver)

    mouseOver_line <- input$mapPlot_mouseOver$state

    line <- datag %>%
      filter(line == mouseOver_line) %>%
      select(-line)})
                                         
                                          
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So far I was able to make the map change by selecting the years but I don't know how to achieve the mouse event. Currently the line graph is shown on the side but the information it shows is incorrect and the interconnectivity that I expect does not work.

**I attach an image of how the dashboard is currently:**
[image: Dashboard]

**My idea is to base myself on this dashboard example:**
[Dashboard](https://jbkunst.shinyapps.io/08-idb-viz/)

Code:
[Source](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter-shiny/tree/master/08-idb-viz)

**I thank you for reading my problem and I would appreciate any ideas on how to continue with this project. Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**
In the end I ended up using the 'click' event instead of the one I had originally thought of. I share the code in case someone happens to have the same thing as me:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Map Test')

sideBar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(fluidPage(column(width = 4,
                                       offset = 4,
                                       selectInput('year',
                                                   label = 'Year',
                                                   choices = unique(years),
                                                   selected = 2018,
                                                   width = "100%"))),
                      box(title = "Map",
                          status = "primary",
                          solidHeader = TRUE,
                          collapsible = TRUE,
                          highchartOutput('mapPlot')),
                      box(title = 'line',
                          solidHeader = TRUE,
                          collapsible = TRUE,
                          highchartOutput('linePlot')))

ui <- dashboardPage(header,
                    sideBar,
                    body)


server <- function(input,
                   output,
                   session)
{
  
  df <- reactive({df <- massShootings.order %>%
    filter(year(date) == input$year) %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    summarise(dead = sum(dead),
              injured = sum(injured),
              total = sum(total),
              description, .groups = 'drop')})
  
  
  output$mapPlot <- renderHighchart({
    
    fn <- "function(){
      console.log(this.name);
      Shiny.onInputChange('mapPlotinput', this.name)
    }"
    
  hcmap(map = 'countries/us/custom/us-all-mainland.js',
        data = df(),
        joinBy = c('name', 'state'),
        value = 'total',
        borderWidth = 0.05,
        nullColor = "#d3d3d3") %>%
    hc_title(text = 'Mass Shooting') %>%
    hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops(colors = viridisLite::viridis(10,
                                                                   begin = 0.1)),
                 type = "logarithmic") %>%
    hc_tooltip(formatter= JS("function () { return this.point.name.bold() +
                            ' <br />' +
                            ' <br /> <b>Dead:</b> ' + this.point.dead +
                            ' <br /> <b>Injured:</b> ' + this.point.injured ;}")) %>%
    hc_add_theme(hc_my_theme) %>%
    hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE) %>%
    hc_credits(enabled = FALSE) %>%
    hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
    hc_plotOptions(series = list(cursor = "pointer", point = list(events = list(click = JS(fn)))))})
  
  
  
  output$linePlot <- renderHighchart({
    
    nme <- ifelse(is.null(input$mapPlotinput), "United States of America", input$mapPlotinput)
    
    dfClick <- massShootings.order %>%
      filter(state %in% nme) %>%
      filter(year(date) == input$year) %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      summarise(dead = sum(dead),
                injured = sum(injured),
                total = sum(total),
                .groups = 'drop')
  
    
    highchart(type = "stock") %>%
      hc_chart("line",
               name = "base",
               hcaes(x = date)) %>%
      hc_add_series(dfClick,
                    name = "Total",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = total)) %>%
      hc_add_series(dfClick,
                    name = "Dead",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = dead)) %>%
      hc_add_series(dfClick,
                    name = "Injured",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = injured)) %>%
      hc_tooltip(
        crosshairs = TRUE,
        shared = TRUE,
        borderWidth = 2,
        table = TRUE)})
                                          
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**The code I added was the following:**

Inside`output$mapPlot <- renderHighchart({})`:

```
fn <- "function(){
      console.log(this.name);
      Shiny.onInputChange('mapPlotinput', this.name)
    }"
```

Inside `hcmap`:

```
hc_plotOptions(series = list(cursor = "pointer", point = list(events = list(click = JS(fn)))))})
```

Inside `output$linePlot <- renderHighchart({})`:

```
nme <- ifelse(is.null(input$mapPlotinput), "United States of America", input$mapPlotinput)
    
    dfClick <- massShootings.order %>%
      filter(state %in% nme) %>%
      filter(year(date) == input$year) %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      summarise(dead = sum(dead),
                injured = sum(injured),
                total = sum(total),
                .groups = 'drop')
```

To create the chart use the information stored in `dfClick`:

```
highchart(type = "stock") %>%
      hc_chart("line",
               name = "base",
               hcaes(x = date)) %>%
      hc_add_series(dfClick,
                    name = "Total",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = total)) %>%
      hc_add_series(dfClick,
                    name = "Dead",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = dead)) %>%
      hc_add_series(dfClick,
                    name = "Injured",
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(
                      x = date,
                      y = injured)) %>%
      hc_tooltip(
        crosshairs = TRUE,
        shared = TRUE,
        borderWidth = 2,
        table = TRUE)})
```